# Jupyter Notebook - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

[image][image]I am new to using Jupyter, NumPy, and pandas. I was looking for a solution online but I could not find anything to solve the error.

I am trying to load a file.csv but I got an error each time I find a solution. I also tried to upload the file to Jupyter notebook to use just the file directly but my system respond that the file is not there. I convert the file from .txt to .csv assuming that that was the problem but still can't load directly. Thus, I decided to use the long format but still have problems.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/kharm/Dropbox/Jupyter/Assignment/AutoInsurSweden.csv', header=None)
data.head()
```

I got the error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 field in line 12, saw 2
```

If I modify to:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/kharm/Dropbox/Jupyter/Assignment/AutoInsurSweden.csv', header=None, error_bad_lines=False )
data.head()
```

or

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/kharm/Dropbox/Jupyter/Assignment/AutoInsurSweden.csv', header=None, sep='\n')
data.head()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that error suggests that the problem is with the datafile itself not your code, it seems on line 12 of the csv you have an extra data field

Comment: Thanks with your input I was able to solve that problem in the .csv file!  but still cannot load in the correct format. I need to show the numbers not the headers like the first picture, the second one is incorrect. I will upload another picture how looks after the correction in the file.

Comment: im not sure i follow what you mean, i gather that you don't want to include the header in which case the argument header=None should do the trick, are you seeing all the columns you expect to?

Comment: I cannot display the numbers.

Comment: This is the link with the file: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv - I must display the columns X and Y with the values.

Comment: for that file be sure to set the separator using sep=';' though i cannot see any other problem you wold have `data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/kharm/Dropbox/Jupyter/Assignment/winequality-white.csv', header=None, sep=';')` should work just fine (though im not sure why in this case you would not include the header)

Comment: I still cannot display the values after I add sep=';'. Please, See my last picture.

Comment: are you certain that you are loading the correct csv, the one that you shared is not the same as what you have in the example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238169/discussion-between-patrick-and-tristan).

Comment: I don't understand - the download link you share is for wine, but your example is for automobiles - which one should we be working with?

Comment: @Tristan The code that Patrick gave is correct and it seems your file is not correct. I tried that on the link that you shared here is the result: https://ibb.co/5MNnvHf